# Hibernate sequence nextVal resolved but not used (Oracle)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, sequence

Hibernate is not assigning objects ids from the Oracle sequence as expected. Here's what I see in the Hibernate debug logs.

```
DEBUG o.h.SQL:92 - select MY_SEQ.nextval from dual
DEBUG o.h.i.e.SequenceStructure:102 - Sequence value obtained: 22643
DEBUG o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl:73 - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener:118 - Generated identifier: 22594, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
```

The first "sequence value obtained" is correct, 22643 comes right from `MY_SEQ.nextVal` as it says. But then the "generated identifier" that gets used is 22594. What gives?

I've tried tweaking the generator strategy to no avail.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "MY_ID", nullable = false, precision = 6, scale = 0)
private Integer id;
```

I can include my Spring Hibernate context configuration if that'll help. I don't see anything in there that looks obviously relevant.

[Hibernate with Oracle sequence doesn't use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171626) is very probably related, but that deals with gaps while the id I get is *less* than the sequence value obtained.

PS: Other tickets discuss sequence generator strategies that optimize efficiency. A single record of this data is inserted once a month or so, and only from this class. So, efficiency isn't a concern here.

### Update 1

I am able to recreate this in HSQLDB in Oracle emulation mode too. So it's surely a Hibernate issue.

### Update 2

The offset is always exactly 49. The example above correctly fetched 22643 from the sequence, but then resolved 22594 as the next value.

22643-22594=49

In another example, the next sequence value was actually 4, and Hibernate gave me -45.

4-(-45)=49

### Update 3

Subsequent inserts *do not* call the Oracle sequence's nextVal. I suspect JPA/Hibernate is trying to fetch ids in bulk upfront for efficiency.

```
DEBUG o.h.SQL:92 - select MY_SEQ.nextval from dual
DEBUG o.h.i.e.SequenceStructure:102 - Sequence value obtained: 22643
DEBUG o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl:73 - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener:118 - Generated identifier: 22594, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
...
DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener:118 - Generated identifier: 22595, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in my 3rd update, JPA was "fetching 50 ids" from the sequence up front and counting through them in memory for efficiency.

This behavior is specified by `javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator.allocationSize` which defaults to 50.

> (Optional) The amount to increment by when allocating sequence numbers from the sequence.

This isn't at all intuitive to me, [or others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745751/hibernate-sequencegenerator-and-allocationsize), since my Oracle database sequence is supposed to define this behavior and 50 isn't a standard default there.

The quick and dirty solution was to specify `allocationSize=1`:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ",
                   allocationSize = 1)
```

Now the Oracle sequence is incremented for every insert.