# Hibernate having issues with sequence object - unable to call next val

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate entity - and sequence generator with it.

My database is Oracle 12c.

In my sequence generator - it fetches value which is already present in table.

I tried looking out for issue  -  found one simmilar thread 
[Hibernate sequence nextVal resolved but not used (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578770/hibernate-sequence-nextval-resolved-but-not-used-oracle)

But still it did not help .  The issue am facing is - it works some times and it does not work some times

Below is my code snippet -

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_NAME", schema = "SCHEMA")
@SequenceGenerator(name="TABLE_ID_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName="SCHEMA.TABLE_ID_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
public class ImportTransactionDataEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="TABLE_ID",unique=true,nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="TABLE_ID_SEQ_GEN" )
    private int IDColumnPk;
```

ANy help is appreciated , thank you :)

Comment: can you try by replacing `sequenceName="SCHEMA.TABLE_ID_SEQ"` with `sequenceName="TABLE_ID_SEQ"` ?

Comment: yes i tried it already , the issue actually is - this thing does not work sometimes and works sometimes , edited the question accordingly

Comment: have you go through with this ? https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated

Comment: thanks for the comment - i went through it - it does not point me towards solution actually ... i have used the sequence strategy same as mentioned in the above URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well finally - i had come to a solution that i was already using oracle 12 C - decide to go with Identity column on the table it self .

NOTE - but the identity column is not available before Oracle 12c .

I ended up getting better performance also with some fraction , so this work around was sigh of relief for me

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "TABLE_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private int IDColumnPk;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_NAME")
@SequenceGenerator(name="TABLE_ID_SEQ_GEN",sequenceName="TABLE_ID_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
public class ImportTransactionDataEntity {

@Id
@Column(name="TABLE_ID",unique=true,nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,generator="TABLE_ID_SEQ_GEN" )
private int IDColumnPk;
```

it is stored in you database like this the last nummber is the last id used so dont worry about loosing count cause the database does that for you

[image]

Comment: I could have used this  , but then i will lose the track of my - TABLE_ID count , so this won't be a good solution to add auto generation

Comment: your table_id count is kept in the database. ar eyou using sql developper?

Comment: i am using Oracle 12 C , if I use auto generation policy - how can i track it , can you please explain that part as well

Comment: in auto generation, the database will take the last vlue and add 1 to it. i am using it and i can know what id i am currently at from the database. all sequences in the database are in a folder called sequence that you can find under yor database if you are using sqldevelopper

Comment: lets say for exemple you create a sequence that starts with 1 and increments each time you insert. the last id value is always stored in the database you won't lose anything

Comment: thank for the answer , i thought of it but can not go with it -  in my scenario - i have 5 different sequences - in 5 different tables - so by this way - my generated IDs will be of irregular interval , so this will affect the reports later and will be unmanageable

Comment: can you expain a little bit further. do you need all the table to have the same equence?

Comment: unfortunately yes , need them in sequence

Comment: so if your first table has an id of 110 in the second one you need to also use 110 or will you use 111??

Comment: all tables  need to have IDs in sequence - my different table can have same IDs 
 but a single table needs IDs in sequence -  your strategy for generating AUTO sequence is fine - no issues with that  - but it will not be applicable in my case

Comment: that is what i did in first place , which was not working - i think you lost the track of question

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle documentation, the @SequenceGenerator should be added to the field, not to the class:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm#BCGGHADG

so something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_NAME", schema = "SCHEMA")

public class ImportTransactionDataEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="TABLE_ID",unique=true,nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="TABLE_ID_SEQ_GEN" )
    @SequenceGenerator(name="TABLE_ID_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName="SCHEMA.TABLE_ID_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
    private int IDColumnPk;
```

This works for me.

Comment: thanks for the answer , am trying this .. let me try and observe it for a day or two , then will be able to come to know